# Can Code page and locale differ?

Tags: locale, icu

On Windows 7 (64 bit) I set Japan as the locale. On command prompt following is reflected:
LC_ALL: English_United States.1252
LC_CTYPE: English_United States.1252
chcp command: Active Code Page: 932  (which is Japanese)

My question is while converting wchar_t* to char* using ICU library what should be default converter used? In this case "US-ASCII" is used and I am getting garbage result in char*. Input: wchar_t* contains Japanese characters

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?  Are you asking if ICU is behaving correctly, are you asking how to make ICU behave the way you want, or are you asking how to properly convert between char sets on windows?

Comment: I will rephrase in simple way. On Windows code page= 932, ICU API ucnv_getDefaultName() returns "US-ASCII". Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

From the [ICU documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters):

> Depending on system design, setup and APIs, it may not always be
> possible to find a default codepage that fully works as expected...
>
> If you have means of detecting a default codepage name that are more
> appropriate for your application, then you should set that name with
> ucnv_setDefaultName() as the first ICU function call. This makes sure
> that the internally cached default converter will be instantiated from
> your preferred name.

Comment: Thank you. I got the issue. I was using "sbcs" version of ICU library instead of "full" version and that is why was getting "US-ASCII" converter on Japanese locale.